# How to get unique (for 3 attributes) entries in a log file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, unique

I have the following *logfile*:

```
01/01/PARISService.unauthorizedcalls.2017-10-01-01.fe-paris-prod-2c-ro-74d8a8a6.us-west-2.amazon.com.gz:[Operation]getSORByID,[RemoteAddress]10.89.204.27,[ClientName]gurupa,[ApolloEnv]SellerCSWebsite/FE,[AAAClientIdentity]ApolloEnv:SellerCSWebsite/FE/Prod,[AAAClientName]CSCentral,[AuthorizedCall]true,YVEEQQ2QQBSZM8F30BQT,01 Oct 2017 01:31:39,018
01/03/PARISService.unauthorizedcalls.2017-10-01-03.fe-paris-prod-2a-ro-1b832c63.us-west-2.amazon.com.gz:[Operation]getSORByID,[RemoteAddress]10.233.102.239,[ClientName]gurupa,[ApolloEnv]SellerCSWebsite/FE,[AAAClientIdentity]ApolloEnv:SellerCSWebsite/FE/Prod,[AAAClientName]CSCentral,[AuthorizedCall]true,A5GMNC188GFREW6W2Y9C,01 Oct 2017 03:28:28,294
01/05/PARISService.unauthorizedcalls.2017-10-01-05.fe-paris-prod-2b-ro-8ba217f8.us-west-2.amazon.com.gz:[Operation]getSORByID,[RemoteAddress]10.88.153.154,[ClientName]gurupa,[ApolloEnv]SellerCSWebsite/FE,[AAAClientIdentity]ApolloEnv:SellerCSWebsite/FE/Prod,[AAAClientName]CSCentral,[AuthorizedCall]true,QKQN4AQSV5CFQ9GC0T8J,01 Oct 2017 05:09:29,257
01/07/PARISService.unauthorizedcalls.2017-10-01-07.fe-paris-prod-2b-ro-b22446dc.us-west-2.amazon.com.gz:[Operation]getSORByID,[RemoteAddress]10.89.77.133,[ClientName]gurupa,[ApolloEnv]SellerCSWebsite/FE,[AAAClientIdentity]ApolloEnv:SellerCSWebsite/FE/Prod,[AAAClientName]CSCentral,[AuthorizedCall]true,DW20Z9V06419CSX4BV4F,01 Oct 2017 07:20:37,589
```

I want to get unique entries only corresponding to 3 attributes:
*[ClientName]* or *[AAAClientIdentity]* or *[AAAClientName]*.

If any of above 3 attributes are different then it is a unique entry for me.

Can anyone guide me how to do that?

Comment: Please show the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

this oneliner should do:

```
awk -F, '!a[$3 FS $5 FS $6]++' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton thank you! yes.. should use meaningful var-name.